# Wix CloseApplication error

Tags: wix

I wrote an installer with wix 3.9 and it should close my App, if it is opened, during installation.
Following many examples, I wrote this code:

```
<util:CloseApplication 
    Id="CloseApp"
    CloseMessage="yes"
    Description="Close [ProductName] to continue installation"
    RebootPrompt="yes" Target="[ProductName].exe"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="DIRCA_TARGETDIR"
        Before="CostInitialize"><![CDATA[TARGETDIR = ""]]></Custom>
    <Custom Action="WixCloseApplications" 
        Before="InstallValidate"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But when I  run my .msi, it fails and log says:

> Action 15:54:34: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred. 
>   Action start 15:54:34: WixCloseApplicationsDeferred.
>   MSI (s) (A0!94) [15:54:34:804]: Note: 1: 2762 
>   DEBUG: Error 2762:  Unable to schedule operation. The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

What's wrong?

Comment: InstallValidate goes before InstallInitialize. So, try to schedule it after InstallInitialize and before InstallFinalize.

Comment: @AlexJ, I've just set `RebootPrompt="no"`, without changing scheduling and it works. What is the reason?

Comment: Interesting solution, but why do you ignore this relatively clear advice, *`The action must be scheduled between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize`*, you already quoted in your question?

Comment: @Wolf, you're right but, for project specification, I need to close my App before installation starts.